# Background images not displayed with a href

Tags: html, css, background-image, href

I have 2 links. The 2nd link have 2 background images, this images served as an icons. But the images are not displayed.

How to fix this?

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified row" data-toggle="buttons">
<div class="col-xs-5">
<a class="btns btns-small btn btn-default btn-block" role="button" href="/example/"><span class="calculator">Click here</span></a>
</div>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
       <a class="icon-payment-app icon-payment-app-arrow btns btns-small btns-app btn btn-default btn-block" role="button" href="/login/">Login Now</a>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.btn-group{ position: relative; top: 26em; left: 5.50em; }
.btn-group-justified{ width: 50%; }
.btn-group .btn-default{ margin: 0; }
.col-xs-5:first-child a{ padding: 1.15em; }
.col-xs-5:last-child a{ padding: 1.25em 0.15em 1.25em 1.75em }
.icon-payment-app:before{ background: url(/files/icon-mypayment.png); background-position: left center; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 1.50em 1.50em; vertical-align: middle; position: relative; left: 0.25em; }
icon-payment-app-arrow{ padding: 2em; }
.icon-payment-app-arrow:before{ background: url('/files/icon-mypayment-arrow.png'); background-position: right center; background-repeat: no-repeat; vertical-align: middle;  }
```

Images

[image: icon 1]

[image: icon 3]

Comment: Use display inline block to your class called .icon-payment-app and you can give it a width and height. You dont have a full path for the image and neither a screenshot, if you had those i would have helped more.

Comment: i already did that but still the images are not displayed. Please see the updated post with screenshots of images

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with your code.

First, you use `:before`, which creates an empty element identical to yours, which is an `inline` element (`<a>`). An empty `inline` element doesn't have a height or width, so no background will show up. Add content, height, width, and display it as `inline-block` and the background will appear:

```
content: " ";
display: inline-block;
height: 20px;
width: 20px;
```

Second, both your classes `icon-payment-app` and `icon-payment-app-arrow` are added to the same element, so they both share the same `:before`. You'll have to separate them.

**EDIT:** You can use `:before` for the left image and `:after` for the second one like this (modify the height and width to your liking, and you may also want to add some padding or margins):

```css
.btn-group{ position: relative; top: 26em; left: 5.50em; }
.btn-group-justified{ width: 50%; }
.btn-group .btn-default{ margin: 0; }
.col-xs-5:first-child a{ padding: 1.15em; }
.col-xs-5:last-child a{ padding: 1.25em 0.15em 1.25em 1.75em }
.icon-payment-app:before{ content: " "; display: inline-block; height: 20px; width: 20px; background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxUkr.jpg'); background-position: left center; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 1.50em 1.50em; vertical-align: middle; position: relative; left: 0.25em; }
icon-payment-app-arrow{ padding: 2em; }
.icon-payment-app-arrow:after{ content: " "; display: inline-block; height: 20px; width: 20px;background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpvG9.png); background-position: right center; background-repeat: no-repeat; vertical-align: middle;  }
```

```html
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified row" data-toggle="buttons">
<div class="col-xs-5">
<a class="btns btns-small btn btn-default btn-block" role="button" href="/example/"><span class="calculator">Click here</span></a>
</div>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
       <a class="icon-payment-app icon-payment-app-arrow btns btns-small btns-app btn btn-default btn-block" role="button" href="/login/">Login Now</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: do you mean the 2nd image should be in a `span` element?

Comment: It can be anything you want, but a separate element for each class. Or you can merge the two images in one and only use one class. But why do you want to use the images as background anyway? Why don't you simply use `<img>` element?

Comment: How to merge the two images? The images should be displayed in left and right of a text. I just want to prevent the using of <img> tag in terms of image icon

Comment: Yes, I've just noticed that, then that's even easier, just use `:before` for the left image and `:after` for the send one. See my edit. You can use one class if you like, or keep them two separate classes.

Answer (score 0):

How about CSS3 background image? You can place two images on the same class. Below is an example.

```css
.btn-group{ position: relative; top: 26em; left: 5.50em; }
.btn-group-justified{ width: 50%; }
.btn-group .btn-default{ margin: 0; }
.col-xs-5:first-child a{ padding: 1.15em; }
.col-xs-5:last-child a{ padding: 1.25em 0.15em 1.25em 1.75em }
.icon-payment-app{ background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxUkr.jpg), url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpvG9.png'); background-position: 10px 20px, right center; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 1.50em 1.50em; vertical-align: middle; position: relative; left: 0.25em;display:inline-block; width:200px; text-align:center; line-height:30px;border:1px solid #fff000;}
icon-payment-app-arrow{ padding: 2em; }
/*.icon-payment-app-arrow{ background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpvG9.png'); background-position: right center; background-repeat: no-repeat; vertical-align: middle;  }*/
```

```html
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified row" data-toggle="buttons">
<div class="col-xs-5">
<a class="btns btns-small btn btn-default btn-block" role="button" href="/example/"><span class="calculator">Click here</span></a>
</div>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
       <a class="icon-payment-app icon-payment-app-arrow btns btns-small btns-app btn btn-default btn-block" role="button" href="/login/">Login Now</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Note if you use the same class anywhere else the background images will be on that as well. Hope this is what you are after.

Oh and i have removed the before and after selector ;-)

Comment: how can I minimize the space between image and text?

Comment: change the width on the class `.icon-payment-app`

Comment: when I change the width of that class, the size of the href is also resizing. And the images have no space in the border line. Please the update post for the screenshot

Comment: I have added the code to shift the first image to the right a little `background-position: 10px 20px, right center;`, you can either use that **or** you can give your background image a little space around it to make it work.

Comment: but it's only the left image have a space. I tried to use padding but it's not working

Comment: Yes only the left image. What is the width of your anchor? Give me the width and i will update the code. **BUT** i would recommend putting the code back to left center and adding in spaces around your original image so your code works on responsive sites.